# myblock for a proportional gyro turn that randomly fails when in a larger program

Tags: mindstorms, gyro

I have a proportional gyro turn myblock that fails when played in a longer program.  The myblock works perfectly fine when played by itself.  The most confusing thing is that the way it fails seems to be random.  Sometimes you play the program and the turn is too far, sometimes it doesn't turn enough and sometimes it works as expected.  We have had similar problems before with other complex myblocks that seem to misbehave when run in as part of a long program but work fine when run by themselves.

I'm not sure the best way to attach code, so I've linked it to the file here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9eJwUXdFba-T3k0cTdYNTJ0eWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When you run the program do you reset your bot at the right position?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means.  Do you have an example of where and what I should do?

Comment: I've looked at the file, and I don't understand what it's supposed to do. First you have some program called "ManFlower". It includes a bunch of MyBlocks that we are unable to decode, and since you're not showing what they do we can't solve the problem. Then you have another program called "SuperGyroTurn" and it is too confusing and hard to see what your code is doing, without details or at least a detailed walkthrough of the program we won't be able to solve this, so we may have to close your question. Another necessary piece of info required is how the robot moves which is not specified.